# Spring `DynamicPropertySource` property is not available to `EnvironmentPostProcessor` - "chicken & egg"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to develop an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` to add a `PropertySource` to spring `Environment`. (following this [howto](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.8/reference/html/howto.html#howto.application.customize-the-environment-or-application-context)).

This `PropertySource` relies on remote connection to some server (i.e. DB). I want the `server-url` to be provided using standard spring properties (application.properties, etc.).

This work as expected since at the time of `EnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment` invocation, the `Environment` has already been prepared with all the usual property sources that Spring Boot loads by default (including my `server-url` property).

The problem happens when I'm trying to use this `EnvironmentPostProcessor` on integration tests. On such tests I'm running a server using `TestContainers` and providing the `server-url` using `DynamicPropertySource`. It seems that `DynamicPropertySource` is handled **after** the `EnvironmentPostProcessor` thus I'm not able to get the correct `server-url` (so my `EnvironmentPostProcessor` can't connect correctly to fetch properties).

What it the recommended way to provide a custom `PropertySource` which relies on remote connection that should be configured externally (via tests too)?

Note: I'm aware of spring-cloud [PropertySourceLocator](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html#customizing-bootstrap-property-sources) but would like to achieve the same without dependency on bootstrap context.

MyEnvironmentPostProcessor (registered via META-INF/spring.factories):

```java
public class MyEnvironmentPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @Override
  public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment,
                                     SpringApplication application) {

    String serverUrl = environment.getProperty("server-url");

    // use serverUrl to connect and create a PropertySource
    PropertySource remotePropertySource = ...

    // adding the remotePropertySource to Environment
    environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(remotePropertySource);
  }
}
```

Test code:

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class DemoApplicationTest {

  // This will use TestContainers to spawn my remote server (etcd in this case)
  @RegisterExtension
  static EtcdClusterExtension cluster = EtcdClusterExtension.builder().build();

  // Using dynamic property source to provide correct value of remote server, hopefully to be used
  // by MyEnvironmentPostProcessor
  @DynamicPropertySource
  static void remoteServerProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    registry.add("server-url", cluster::clientEndpoints);
  }
}
```